# using multiple property sheets in VStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, propertysheet

How do you correctly use multiple property sheets in VStudio?

Assuming I want to have two separate propsheets for two libraries A and B then what I do is create sheet 1 for library A where I enter all the required directory paths and stuff. This alone works fine. If I then create sheet 2 for library B and inherit all settings from the parent sheet (in this case sheet 1) then in VStudio the paths of lib A are shown and the propsheet file of lib B only contains empty XML nodes - so far so good. But as soon as I add a new library path in sheet 2, it not only saves it in it's according propsheet file but also the inherited values from sheet 1. Hence, everytime I add sheet 2 to a new project, it also includes the paths of lib A. How do I prevent this?